# Understanding open and listening ports

Tags: java, server, tcp

I developed an app in Java (which is working perfectly; with this app you can scan TCP/UDP ports -for testing purposes only-), but meanwhile when I was writing the code I read several documentation (wiki) about sockets. I thought open port is mean, a protocol where the client/server can establish/bind a connection even if there are nothing on the server side which can handle/response data. I thought open port is mean (if there are no routers/firewalls) a protocol which is ready to be used.

I was testing my application on my local server machine, but at first I thought my application is not working. It was working, but there was no any software which could response to my queries. After I opened my APACHE server and I wrote a simple UDP server (which can handle/response to any query on a specific port) the application was able to find those ports.

I thought listening port is a port which is used and it's opened. What does listening port is meaning?

If I send UDP packets to a remote host and there are no closed ports (router or firewall) what happens to the packet? Does the data is written in the buffer? Or it simply ignores/denies the packet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listening ports are used in servers. If you have an apache web server for example, it does not know in advance when it will be used. **Listening** means that it just waits (like a recepcionist in a hotel :) and it is ready to send an answer whenever a client program (a browser for example) requests it. The connection becomes **open** when a client connects to that port and a conversation begins.

If no program is listening on a port, and a client tries to connect, then the operating system will reject it.